# Comparing nested mice models with interaction terms

Tags: r, r-mice

R's `mice` contains a function, `pool.compare`, to compare nested models fit to imputed objects. If I try to include an interaction term:

```
library(mice)
imput = mice(nhanes2)
mi1 <- with(data=imput, expr=lm(bmi~age*hyp))
mi0 <- with(data=imput, expr=lm(bmi~age+hyp))
pc  <- pool.compare(mi1, mi0, method="Wald")
```

then it returns the following error:

```
Error in pool(fit1) : 
  Different number of parameters: coef(fit): 6, vcov(fit): 5
```

It sounds like the variance-covariance matrix doesn't include the interaction term as its own variable. What's the best way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem appears to be that some of your parameters are un-estimatable in some of your imputed data.sets. When I run the code, I see

```
( fit1<-mi1$analyses[[1]] )
# lm(formula = bmi ~ age * hyp)
# 
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)         age2         age3         hyp2    age2:hyp2  
#      28.425       -5.425       -3.758        1.200        3.300  
#   age3:hyp2  
#          NA
```

In this set, it was not possible to estimate `age3*hyp2` (presumably because there were no observations in this group).

This causes the discrepancy in  `coef(fit1)` and `vcov(fit1)` since the covariance cannot be estimated for that term.

What to do in this case is more of a statistical problem than a programming problem. If you are unsure of what would be appropriate for your data, I suggest you consult with the statisticians over at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).